# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished sample_app RoR Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting an error: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished when I view the application in the browser (full trace below).  I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.  I have tried items mentioned below:

here http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2011/09/15/activerecordconnectionnotestablished-in-rails-3-1-on-heroku/

as well as here stackoverflow.com/questions/7871233/ruby-activerecordconnectionnotestablished

and here www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2854331

and multiple others

(FYI, am running on Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.3, no RVM)
My Code available here: https://github.com/justjoehere/sample_app

Any help would be greatly appreciated

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

database yaml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Trace:

> activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
>
> activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
>
> activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
>
> activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
>
> activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
>
> activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
>
> activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `*run*_133064122_*call*_765555415__callbacks'
>
> activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
>
> activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>
> activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
>
> railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
>
> activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
>
> railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>
> activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'

Comment: Can you post here what is in your database.yml ?

Comment: # SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Comment: Apparently, I found some sort of bad dependency in the gems.  The issue resolved itself when I moved to 

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3','1.3.8'
gem 'rspec-rails'